# Building a 2D Game Engine from scratch or learn Cocos 2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, game-engine

As the title says, next year I´ll be focusing in on game programming on mobile devices. And I am unsure if I should start straight with learning Cocos2D as there are alot of great teaching materials for this engine, and I think it is quite capable. Or should I learn to program my own engine - I have this 400page book by Michael Daley wich teaches you to build a simple 2d engine and game ground up using particle effects, tilemaps and all that...

My question is would there be any great advantages of knowing how an game engine is built from scratch and then move to learning Cocos2D or could i safely just drop this and move straight to learning the Cocos framework? and is it especially hard building a 2D engine, etc.. do I need any specific math skills and such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only for iPhone then [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org) is best option. To support android too then use [cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org)

Cocos2D   : Objective C - 2D game engine for iOS

Cocos2D-X : C++ based game engine for iOS / Android

Comment: is Cocos2D-X the same as Cocos2D - meaning the libraries works the same way? only that I use C++ instead of ObjC to program in. And then I could use that code for both iOS and Android and just have to create two seperate 'interfaces' for the code to run in on both OS´es?

Comment: if it is c++, cross platform 2D game engine then cocos2d-x is best option for you.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you need to decide whether your goal is to create a 2d game or to learn how to make a 2d game engine. If your goal is to make a game right away then I would use some ready-made engine. I'm not familiar with Cocos2D so I can't say if it is a good choice, though.

Comment: Cocos2D got good cross-platform support, there are lot´s of books and tutorials on it and it is open-source and free to use. I am assuming it can´t be to shabby with all this going for it.

Comment: Cocos2D is great! It makes making games so much better that having to work on an engine as well. I second what @Joakim Gebart said as well.